# hide a mat-hint when matInput is disabled

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm looking to have a hint only display when its corresponding input is enabled.

```
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Site Name</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            [disabled]="disableEditSiteName()"
            required
            [(ngModel)]="site.siteName"
            [value]="site.siteName"
          />
          <mat-hint align="start"> Required </mat-hint>
        </mat-form-field>
```

In the above, when disableEditSiteName() is true I would like to hide the hint. This could be done with *ngIf, however if there was a way to hide all mat-hints if their input was set to disabled that would mean less code repetition.

Comment: I have tried the following CSS with no luck:

`.mat-input:disabled + .mat-hint {  display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using `*ngIf`**

On your html code, `disableEditSiteName()` function result decides to disable or enable the `input`.

So you can use that value for `mat-hint`.

If `disableEditSiteName()` function returns `true`, you should hide `mat-hint` and if it returns false, you should show `mat-hint`.

This can be done using `*ngIf` as follows.

```
<mat-hint align="start" *ngIf="!disableEditSiteName()"> Required </mat-hint>
```

**2. Using CSS**
You can hide `mat-hint` using `+` selector on CSS as follows.

```
input[disabled] + .mat-hint {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi Derek,
Thanks for this answer. As I asked in the question, but perhaps not clearly enough, I would prefer not to have to repeat the *ngIf on each mat-form-field and was hoping there was a way to do this to all hints and their respective inputs based on the disabled status of the input.

Comment: I have updated my answer using `CSS`. `input[disabled] + .mat-hint { display: none; }` will work.

Comment: Then you can try like this with return value of funciton like `input[disabled="true"] + .mat-hint { display: none; }`

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my previous comment that said it worked with `input[required] + .mat-hint { display: none; }` as it turned out it didn't work (I was looking at inputs without hints).

The above is still not working.

Comment: I have also tested `input[disabled="true"] ~ .mat-hint { display: none; }`
When inspecting the page in Chrome it appears that the input and the mat-hint have separate parents. The inputs parent is `mat-form-field-flex` while the mat-hint parent is `mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper`.